# Can I repeat a std::string_view without copying when printing indentation?

Tags: c++, logging, string-view

I have a simple scene in C++ code.
I want to get a long string containing some repeated `std::string_view`; is there a way to achieve this without copying the string?

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <string_view>

struct Logger {
    static inline constexpr std::string_view indent = "    ";
    static inline int level = 0;

    Logger() {
        level++;
    }

    // ...
    
    void log(const std::string &msg) {
        std::printf(/* repeat indent 'level' times */);
    }
};
```

Comment: why not a loop ?

Comment: No, you'll have to copy into a new string. If you know in advance the maximum number of indents you'll need you could prepare a constant with the maximum length

Comment: You could make a constexpr function thate creates a std::array<std::string_view,N> with different levels of indentation.

Comment: `views::repeat` with `std::format` can do that.

Comment: @康桓瑋 `std::format` returns a `std::string`, so that is copying.

Comment: @康桓瑋 The OP seems to just want indentation, I'd [play](https://godbolt.org/z/77KrvszjK) with the align specifier.

Comment: @JanSchultke I mean C++23`std::print`.

Comment: I would recommend to use ready library for logging. [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog) is pretty cool and based on fmt.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I don't think you can print a `std::ranges::repeat_view` directly anyways; it would have to be put into a `std::string` as an intermediate step. You could however set a fill-character in the format string to print indentation.

Comment: @JanSchultke [Formatting Ranges](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2286r8.html).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I have to send all the characters together to a function in my project, so a loop cannot resolve my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### C-Style Solution

`std::printf` allows you to dynamically specify the field width. For example:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    int indent_length = 4;
    int indent_depth = 3;

    // note: "" is passed as an argument for %s
    std::printf("%*shi!", indent_length * indent_depth, "");
}
```

This will output:

```
            hi!
```

We can use this trick because indentation always consist of one character, so we don't really have to repeat a full `std::string_view`.
Obviously, this wouldn't work if you wanted indentation that is a mixture of multiple characters, but that would be highly unusual.

#### Old-School C++ Solution

However, that is a very C-style solution, and you could just use a loop to avoid copying:

```cpp
void log(std::string_view msg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < level; ++i) {
        std::cout << indent;
    }
    std::cout << msg;
}
```

However, if the indent is not a mixture of different characters,
we can do a similar trick using `std::cout` as above to avoid this loop:

```cpp
void log(std::string_view msg) {
    std::cout << std::setw(indent_length * level) << "" << msg;
}
```

If you absolutely insist on using `std::printf`, we can still do:

```cpp
// if msg is always null-terminated
std::printf("%s", msg.data());

// otherwise
std::printf("%.*s", int(msg.length()), msg.data());
```

Your `indent` string can be printed exactly the same way.

Comment: What does the first snippet has to do with the question?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the purpose of the question is to `printf` indentation a variable amount of times. Since the indentation is always a single a single character, we don't really need to repeat a full `std::string_view`, but we can repeat a single character.

Comment: there is `fmt` library and `spdlog` based on it. Since C++23 there is `std::print` motivated by `fmt::print`. `fmt::print("{:{}}", "", indent);`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer to you question is **NO**,

but `std::views::repeat` or `std::ranges::repeat_view` can help you write more concise and more readable code.

In alternative, if you know a priori the max indentation, you could initialize a `std::array` of `string_view`, where the dimension is the number of max indentation, where each `string_view`, have incremental repetion of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would try do longest possible ident and then extract subview form it:

```cpp
using namespace std::string_view_literals;

constexpr auto MaxIndentView = "                                            "sv;

constexpr std::string_view indentView(size_t n)
{
    if (n * 4 > MaxIndentView.size()) {
        throw std::invalid_argument{"Max indentation reached"};
    }
    return MaxIndentView.substr(0, n * 4);
}
```

But I think this is not what you actually need.